# Adding click listener to two buttons in PagerAdpater CardViews

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-pageradapter

In my project, I have a PagerAdapter to inflate CardViews that hold text objects created by the user.

On each CardView I have edit and delete buttons to access methods to do with the ArrayList holding the text objects.

I have coded an interface in my adapter to handle clicks made within the text object creation activity. However, my instatiateItem method in my adapter is now showing on the @Override annotation "Method does not override method from its superclass". When I remove the @Override annotation I get an error in my Logcat:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Required method instantiateItem was not overridden
```

How do I implement a click listener for buttons on a CardView in a PagerAdapter?

Adapter code:

```
public class CreateAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private List<PdfPage> pagesList;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context context;
private onItemClickListener mListener;

public interface onItemClickListener{
    //click method for edit button
    void onEditClick(int position);
    //click method for delete button
    void onDeleteClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}

public CreateAdapter(List<PdfPage> pagesList, Context context) {
    this.pagesList = pagesList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pagesList.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position, final onItemClickListener listener) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = null;

    if(pagesList.get(position).getPageType() == "Text") {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.create_text_cardview, container, false);

        TextView inputText = view.findViewById(R.id.inputTextView);
        ImageButton editButton = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonEdit);
        ImageButton deleteButton = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonDelete);

        //if this works, see 12:30 of video for image getter
        inputText.setText(pagesList.get(position).getPageText());

        //edit click listener
        editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null){
                    int position2 = pagesList.indexOf(pagesList.get(position));
                    listener.onEditClick(position2);
                }
            }
        });

        //delete click listener
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null){
                    int position3 = pagesList.indexOf(pagesList.get(position));
                    listener.onDeleteClick(position3);
                }
            }
        });

        container.addView(view, 0);

    }

    //put else statement here for image cardView

    assert view != null;
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((View)object);
}
```

Activity code:

```
public class CreateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
CreateAdapter createAdapter;
List<PdfPage> pdfPageList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);

    pdfPageList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    createAdapter = new CreateAdapter(pdfPageList, this);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(createAdapter);
    viewPager.setPadding(130, 0, 130, 0);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    createAdapter = new CreateAdapter(pdfPageList, this);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(createAdapter);
    viewPager.setPadding(130, 0, 130, 0);

    createAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new CreateAdapter.onItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEditClick(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
            pdfPageList.remove(position);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `instantiateItem` method does not override from it's superclass because you added an extra argument `final onItemClickListener listener`.

As you are using the same clickListener for all entries and passing the item position as an argument, I suggest that you pass the `onItemClickListener` in the adapter constructor, or just set it via

```
public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}
```

Adapter code:

```
public class CreateAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private List<PdfPage> pagesList;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context context;
private onItemClickListener mListener;

public interface onItemClickListener{
    //click method for edit button
    void onEditClick(int position);
    //click method for delete button
    void onDeleteClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}

public CreateAdapter(List<PdfPage> pagesList, Context context) {
    this.pagesList = pagesList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pagesList.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = null;

    if(pagesList.get(position).getPageType() == "Text") {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.create_text_cardview, container, false);

        TextView inputText = view.findViewById(R.id.inputTextView);
        ImageButton editButton = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonEdit);
        ImageButton deleteButton = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonDelete);

        //if this works, see 12:30 of video for image getter
        inputText.setText(pagesList.get(position).getPageText());

        //edit click listener
        editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mlistener != null){
                    int position2 = pagesList.indexOf(pagesList.get(position));
                    mlistener.onEditClick(position2);
                }
            }
        });

        //delete click listener
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mlistener != null){
                    int position3 = pagesList.indexOf(pagesList.get(position));
                    mlistener.onDeleteClick(position3);
                }
            }
        });

        container.addView(view, 0);

    }

    //put else statement here for image cardView

    assert view != null;
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((View)object);
}
```

And your Activity code could stay as it is.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have fixed it but now I'm getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException on int position3 = pagesList.indexOf(pagesList.get(position)); in the delete click listener. Any ideas?

Comment: I called onStart again after delete and this fixed it, thanks again!